# Feeding data from GCS csv zipped bucket into tensorflow model in batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bigdata

I have a training data (~500GB) stored in google cloud storage buckets. The data is in the format of csv zipped files and is distributed in different buckets. I want to use tensorflow's multi-worker distribution strategy to train my keras functional model.

I could only find `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` api to read a csv file on gcs. But this is not working for me. I am getting below error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 10: invalid start byte
```

Also, I have to do transformation on this data before feeding into model. How can I achieve all that ?